# How do I delete the last two letters of a string?

Tags: java

Problem:

Prompt the user for a String and check to see if it is plural (ends in “s” or “es”). Output the singular form of the word.  If the user input a singular word simply output the word.

Example:

- Input a plural word (ending in s or es):
  Houses
- Singular version of the word: House

How am I supposed to print out the word that does not have "es"?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
System.out.println("Input a plural word: ");
String pluralWord = kb.nextLine();
if (pluralWord.substring(pluralWord.length()-2).equals("es") || pluralWord.substring(pluralWord.length()-2).equals("s"))
    System.out.println("Singular version of the word:"+ );
```

Comment: Look at the API for String. You are looking for methods that can give you substring locations within a String (perhaps starting at the end) so you can extract a substring. Also look at endsWith(), which is more appropriate here, I think.

Comment: I know how to use .endsWith(), but how do print the word out?

Comment: You want to create a new singular String that is a substring of the plural. Well, that's one way. The API is a wide-open book. Read the method descriptions and you will get some ideas.

Comment: Is "houses" word just an example? , If you want to parse plural ends you need a dictionary for that otherwise you will ecounter the issues. Flies -> fly in this example singular form is not "fli"

Comment: @HyunseokSong, pleased keep in mind there are many English words this will not work for: knives, mice, geese, cacti, men, feet, fish, etc. http://web2.uvcs.uvic.ca/elc/studyzone/330/grammar/irrplu.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Input a plural word: ");
String pluralWord = kb.nextLine();

if(pluralWord.substring(pluralWord.length()-2).equals("es")){
   System.out.println("Singular version of the word:"+ pluralWord.substring(0, pluralWord.length()-2));
}else if(pluralWord.substring(pluralWord.length()-1).equals("s")){
   System.out.println("Singular version of the word:"+ pluralWord.substring(0, pluralWord.length()-1));
}else{
   System.out.println("Singular version of the word:"+ pluralWord);
}
```

Comment: NO, I dont want the last 2 letters to print out. I want the first letters to print out,

Comment: If only substring() took more than one argument. If only.

Comment: @HyunseokSong Forgot first argument of substring method ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Format String Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) with `printf`. Also, [`String.endsWith(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith%28java.lang.String%29) and then [`substring(0, len - 2)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) and/or `substring(0, len - 1)` like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input a word: ");
    String pluralWord = kb.nextLine();
    if (pluralWord.endsWith("es")) {
        System.out.printf("Plural %s, Singular %s%n", pluralWord,
                pluralWord.substring(0, pluralWord.length() - 2));
    } else if (pluralWord.endsWith("s")) {
        System.out.printf("Plural %s, Singular %s%n", pluralWord,
                pluralWord.substring(0, pluralWord.length() - 1));
    } else {
        System.out.printf("Singular %s%n", pluralWord);         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Input a plural word: ");
String pluralWord = kb.nextLine();


if(pluralWord.length() > 1 && plurpluralWord.substring(pluralWord.length()- 2).equals("es") {
        System.out.println("Singular version of the word:"+
         pluralWord.substring(0 , pluralWord.length()-2));
}else if (pluralWord.length() > 0  && pluralWord.substring(pluralWord.length()- 1).equals("s")){
      System.out.println("Singular version of the word:"+ pluralWord.substring(0 , pluralWord.length()-1));
}else{
      System.out.println("Singular version of the word:"+ pluralWord);
}
```